# Using bash, how to extract specific image's URL and title text from html file?

Tags: linux, bash

Given several hundred numerically ordered html files, each having multiple image tags but only one image with the id I'm looking for and following the convention

```
<img title="$titleText" src="$imgURL" id="foo" border="0" />
```

where `$imgURL` and `$titleText` are unique to each page and are not predictable as the page's URL is (predictable), and the image I want on each page has `id="foo"` (same on each page, other images having a different or no id).

How would I go about extracting the `$imgURL` and `$titleText` strings in `bash`?

So far I'm looking at a starting point of

```
for count in `seq 1 400`; 
   do page="https://website/$count.html"; 
   imgURL=[somehow get $imgURL from $page];
   titleText=[somehow get $titleText from $page];
   echo -e "$count\n$titleText\n$imgURL\n\n" >> some-file; 
done
```

but with no real idea about how to accomplish the parts in brackets.
It will probably have to involve at least two of `sed`/`grep`/`curl`/`wget`.

### Edit: 95% answered by JoW below, the last couple details follow here

After JoW pointed me in the right direction I was able to figure out the rest easily. The final script used, which had the same intended effect as the "starting point" bash code above, was:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
for count in xrange(1, 400):
    ct = str(count)
    url = "website/" + ct + ".html"
    data = requests.get("https://" +url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
    for link in soup.findAll("img", {"id": "foo"}):
        with open('some-file', "a") as out:
            out.write(ct + "\n" + link['title'] + "\n" + link['src'] + "\n\n")
```

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser _polyisoprene_.  After you created the address of `page` you have to download it (maybe with wget). You can even redirect to the StdOut and filter (to avoid to write on the disk as you can). I find not clean what you will find inside that page. You have to individuate the _unique_ tags that will allow to select only the interesting part of the file (if in the page there are many images you will find many tags `<img .... />`, or is this the unique because it is all in a single tag and not `<img a>... </a>`? Please [edit] your post to specify better, it will help to answer.

Comment: Sorry, rereading above I can see it being a bit ambiguous - it's unique because it has `id="foo"` in the `<img ... />` tag - other images have a different id or none.

Comment: Usually it is [not a good idea to parse an html file with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3569208), but you can try to adapt, e.g., this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1736801/3569208) to your needs with `sed`. As usual `man sed` , `man wget` ... the use of `|` to pipe the output in some other command...

Comment: Fair enough, so I'd need to figure how to parse the html to lift the `<img ... />` tag with `id="foo"` in it? If I get that far I should be able to figure out how to use `sed` or `grep` to isolate `$imgURL` and `$titleText`, but when I tried `xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@id="foo"]' https://website/1.html` I got a bunch of errors (e.g. `HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'`) in addition to the tag I was looking for and can't figure out how to get rid of them (using `--nowarning` makes no difference) - any idea how to fix that or an alternate approach to net the desired result?

Comment: Without an html example file to test on, it is difficult to do whatever you want to try... 
In general: Download one html page, Then test on this one locally. After generalize with the loop and maybe without writing the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently had to work with a similar problem and after countless hours of frustration, I ended up using python with BeautifulSoup4, which I should have used from the start—and so should you in my opinion. It is MUCH easier to work with as it is actually built for this type of exercise (i.e. parsing HTML). You can easily write a python script using BS4, collecting all your image URLs in a file, and then call that script from bash.

That's what I'd do.

Edit:

Here's a quick sample of what this could look like:

```
#!/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html")) 

for link in soup.findAll("img", {"id": "foo"})
  print(link['src'])
```

Obviously this only checks one file (index.html) and prints the link to stoud. For your purpose you'd either write the whole thing in python (i.e. loop through the files here) or pass the file names from bash to your python script. In any case you'll probably want to write URL to an output file.

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as out:
 out.write(link['src'])
```

Comment: Never used Python before so I wouldn't have thought of this (and even then it took a while to get it to do exactly what I wanted it to do), but you got me ~95% the way there and I've edited my question to include the blanks I filled in. Thanks!